# Issue running bash script as response to Interactive prompts

Tags: shell-script, interactive

I am having some issues with running a shell script within an interactive prompt. The entire code works fine and if I replace the bash script with an echo 'hello world' line it works without any issues. I am not a long time experienced user of using the shell so I would appreciate it any answer that comes with an explanation.

So basically what I am trying to do is to have an interactive shell script prompt me if I want to commence running another script to start backing up my data.

I have tried running the main script (bash my_script.sh) using the bash command and i get the following error.

```
main_backup_pend.sh: line 17: bash: command not found
```

Where line 17 is where i call the bash script seen below...

```
[Yy]* ) echo 'Copying database...'; bash $PATH/backup.database.sh > backup.log.$DATE.database; break;;
```

---

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=/data/sjamal/4.Backups
DATE=170317

#[COPY]Mysqldump, making database copy storing it locally

    while true; do
    read -p "Do you wish make a database copy?" yn
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) echo 'Copying database...'; bash $PATH/backup.database.sh > backup.log.$DATE.database; break;;
        [Nn]* ) break;;
        * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
    esac
done

#[BACKUP]Performing back up of Repository to HPC

    while true; do
    read -p "Do you wish to back up Repository to HPC?" yn
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) echo 'backing up Repository...'; bash $PATH/backup.Repository.sh > backup.log.$DATE.repository; break;;
        [Nn]* ) break;;
        * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
    esac
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line of your script breaks everything:

```
PATH=/data/sjamal/4.Backups
```

What this tells your script is that all its commands - including the `bash` interpreter itself - live exclusively in this directory. (Perhaps you didn't know that `PATH` is a reserved variable? Try `echo $PATH` sometime to see the list of directories that are usually searched for commands.)

Change your use of `PATH` throughout the script to something else, perhaps `backup_dir` and it's more likely to work as expected.

---

Other hints: put your variables (and paths using variables) in `"$double_quotes"` when you use them. So instead of `backup.log.$DATE.repository` use `"backup.log.$DATE.repository"`.

Comment: Oh of course! I feel so stupid to have missed that. The error message had me doubting completely different things.